# Object becomes duplicated in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Im trying to add an object to `NSMutableArray` it seems to get duplicated.

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject {
    double a_actual;
    double a_target;
}
@property(assign) double a_actual;
@property(assign) double a_target;
```

Create some pointers:

```
NSMutableArray * myTestObjectArray;
TestObject * myTestObject;
```

Init them:

```
myTestObjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
myTestObject = [[TestObject alloc] init];
```

I add value to the object and add it to the array:

```
[myTestObject setA_actual:234];
[myJointDataArray insertObject:myTestObject];
```

I add different values to each object, but i do not necessarily fill all the variables out.
When i print each object out i have the same (last) value duplicated in all objects for some reason.

Printing the array shows that all objects are the same:

```
 Array: (
     "<TestObject: 0x6b9b400>",
     "<TestObject: 0x6b9b400>",
     "<TestObject: 0x6b9b400>",
     "<TestObject: 0x6b9b400>",
     "<TestObject: 0x6b9b400>",
     "<TestObject: 0x6b9b400>" )
```

Should i alloc a new object of TestObject everytime i want to work with a new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should i alloc a new object of TestObject everytime i want to work with a new?

Yes.  If you don't allocate a new object, you're just working with the same object over and over again.  It appears you want multiple, distinct objects, so allocate a new instance for each one.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more clear to you why it is failing, consider that `insertObject:` takes a pointer to an object as a parameter. So when you send the `insertObject:` message to your array, it will store a pointer to that object, not a copy of the object itself. That's why you have to alloc/init a new instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically adding the same object. If you check the value of "a_actual" for each object inside your array, you will see it's the same. **You should allocate a new one and add it**.